# EditText paste Data that cross the limit

Tags: android, android-edittext

In `EditText` maximum limit set to 10. But if user copies data from anywhere else and length of copied data is more than 10 characters user can paste it in the `EditText`.

what is the solution of this problem?

Answer (score -1):

You could try it with a text changed listener:

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           // Check your edittext length here
           if (edittext.getText().toString().length() > 10)
              edittext.setText(edittext.getText().toString().substring(0, 10);
        }
    });
```

Comment: how this can provide answer to question

Comment: You can check the edittexts' length in "afterTextChanged" or probably in "onTextChanged". If The length is more than the set limit, you can shorten it.

Comment: yes you can do that but you should have provide how to do it in answer instead of just mentioning use TextChangedListener

Comment: setText() calls the TextWatcher you registered so it will end up in a StackOverflowException